# Hosting fastAPI on vast.ai GPU instance

Tags: nginx, cloud, gpu, fastapi

How to allow http traffic on vast.ai instance? I'd like to host GPU related code using fastAPI+nginx, but I am not seeing NGINX homepage after configuration. I am not seeing bad gateway error. What I am getting is "This site can’t be reached".

After configuration, I wanted to see Nginx homepage. It works on AWS, but when setting the instance on AWS, you get the option of choosing "Allow http/https traffic". On vast.ai, I do not see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `False Genius` mentioned, we can use a combination of FastAPI and ngrok.

Solution:

1. In the terminal, run your FastAPI app with the command: `uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`
2. Next, create or open a Jupyter Notebook. Enter the following: `!ngrok authtoken YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN` and then `!ngrok http 8000`

Then it should works :)

Comment: Awesome. This works 100%! Thank you so so much for this one!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it didn't work by ssh-ing into the instance and running the fastAPI.

I rented another instance with Jupyter Notebook enabled.

So Jupyter + ngrok + uvicorn works. Since vast.ai instance IP isn't accessible, ngrok does the trick by providing a unique ip